# Azure powershell - how to pull

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I have an Azure powershell script that's pulling an XML file and then running the values through a 'foreach' loop.

I have a blob file in Azure storage with the following format (XML) -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <Root>
<PublicSubnets>
<Subnet>192.168.1.0/24</Subnet>
<Subnet>192.168.50.0/24</Subnet>
<Subnet>10.82.19.5/24</Subnet>
<Subnet>10.1.1.0/16</Subnet>
<Subnet>172.16.15.0/16</Subnet>
 </PublicSubnets>
<Descrip>
<Description>"This is the description"</Description>
</Descrip>
</Root>
```

The idea is for an azure powershell script to loop through the XML and create a network security group entry for each of them.  **That part works just fine.**

What i'm trying to do is instead of ingesting a XML file, I want it to be a Json with all the subnet values.

Here's the current script (note that $nsgname and $resourcegroupname are entered by the user, for a network security group that the script will then create NSG entries for each subnet in the XML file)

```
$Url = "https://theteststorage.blob.core.windows.net/params/SubnetParams.xml?st=2018-10-25T19andrestoftheURL"
$Subnets = @()
[xml]$xml = Invoke-WebRequest $Url -UseBasicParsing | Select-Object -Expand Content

$counter=0
foreach ($subnet in $xml.Root.PublicSubnets.Subnet) 
{
$counter++
Write-Output "Counter is at $counter and subnet is $subnet"
}
```

This should print out:
    Counter is at 1 and subnet is 192.168.1.0/24
    Counter is at 2 and subnet is 192.168.50.0/24

How would I go about doing that but instead of XML, it would be Json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is that download the json file content as string and then convert it to Powershell object using `ConvertFrom-Json`.

Please follow the code as below:

```
$url="https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/t1s/test.json"
$subnets=@()
$web_client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$download_json = $web_client.DownloadString($url)

#convert the download string to a PowerShell object
$json = $download_json | ConvertFrom-Json

$counter=0
foreach($subnet in $json.Root.PublicSubnets.Subnet)
{
$counter++
Write-Output "Counter is at $counter and subnet is $subnet"
}
```

the test.json file:

```
{
  "Root": {
    "PublicSubnets": {
      "Subnet": [
        "192.168.1.0/24",
        "192.168.50.0/24",
        "10.82.19.5/24",
        "10.1.1.0/16",
        "172.16.15.0/16"
      ]
    },
    "Descrip": { "Description": "\"This is the description\"" }
  }
}
```

Test result:
[image]

**Update**:

Or you can use `Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url`, which will parse the json response to PSObject automatically:

[image]

Comment: Worked PERFECTLY.  Thank you!